# WPF how users add images

Tags: wpf, image

What is the best way to allow a user to insert photos for an image viewer? The end result I am looking for would be thumbnails in a listbox that when selected would open in a viewbox. I understand the binding, but I don't know how to get the photos to a folder or whatever from the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question, but if you want the user to select a photo on their disk and then show it, use the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) to choose the file and then use [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) with `Source` set to a [`BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) with `UriSource` set to the filename of the selected image (as shown in the Examples section of docuementation for `Image`).

Comment: Thank-You for your help svick. I will look at the examples.